# Avoiding coupling after splitting class

Tags: java, delegates, refactoring

Often after splitting a class I end up with too many dependencies between them. How to avoid this?

Consider a class that through poor design is trying to do two things. I will keep it very simple here but imagine that there are several methods related to each of the classes identities.

```
class Vehicle {
    public void driveTo(Destination destination);
    public void sellTo(Person purchaser);
}
```

In this case I tend to create separate interfaces for each of the roles played and then change the original class to designate it as `implements` each of those. The actual implementation is then moved to a separate delegate class that is called from the original class.

```
interface Drivable {
    void driveTo(Destination destination);
}

interface Sellable {
    void sellTo(Person purchaser);
}

class Vehicle implements Drivable, Sellable {
    private final Drivable drivableVehicle;
    private final Sellable sellableVehicle;

    public void driveTo(Destination destination) {
        drivableVehicle.driveTo(destination);
    }

    public void sellTo(Person purchaser) {
        sellableVehicle.sellTo(purchaser);
    }
}
```

This works nicely to gather all the related methods together and splits the details of driving and selling into their own class. All good.

My issue with this pattern is that the `Vehicle` class now needs to change every time the interfaces receive a new method which does nothing but call the equivalent in the delegate. For large complex classes with dozens of methods that are being split out I end up with the same dozens of methods calling delegate methods which seems to defeat the purpose of splitting the class.

I have attempted to apply a few different design patterns to resolve this including Visitor and Mediator but none have managed to be neater than the pattern above.

So my question is: is there an elegant way to split a class into several separate roles that it plays while hiding this as an implementation detail and avoiding creating a new maintenance dependency?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your example code is a good portrayal of your question since the splitting/delegating is still not the best design (more on that later). But assuming your real code should use delegation like that, I'm still confused by your complaint

> My issue with this pattern is that the Vehicle class now needs to change every time the interfaces receive a new method which does nothing but call the equivalent in the delegate.

If you never split the methods into 2 classes, wouldn't you still have had to add the new methods to the `Vehicle` class anyway?  So aside from a silly one line method to add, not much is changed.

Now onto the redesign solution.

I don't think delegation is the right solution for your Drivable and Sellable sub-interfaces.

1. Is the car really "sellable" or Has-A "sellable"? Not really.  While technically the car could be sold to another owner, it isn't a core part of the `Vehicle` unlike the tires or engine.  This would imply that all the methods relating to transferring ownership of a Vechile should be completely removed from `Vehicle`. You can have a field that contains information about who the owner is.  But all the code for managing/updating who the owner is should not be in `Vehicle`.
2. Even Drivable might not be something you want to be part of the Vehicle. What happens in `driveTo(Destination)`?  Does the `Vehicle` object have map related fields and path finding algorithms to get from its current position to `destination`? Do we have to compute fuel costs?  Perhaps some of those things should be moved out of `Vehicle` too?

Perhaps a better design is to move those functions into new `Service` classes. That aren't referenced by `Vehicle` at all.  These new Services take a `Vehicle` as input and then call the appropriate methods on the `Vehicle` instead.

So for `Sellable`.  Let's say `Vehicle` has a `Registration` field that is an object that stores the name of the current owner, the date of transfer etc.  Maybe even includes past ownership history.

A `VehicleRegistrationService` would get the current registration, and update it with the new owner's info:

public class VehicleRegistrationService{

```
   public void sellTo(Vehicle v, Person newOwner){
      Registration prevRegistration = v.getRegistration();
      //..complex business logic to update DMV records etc
      Registration newRegistration = new Registration(newId(), prevRegistration);
      newRegistration.setCurrentOwner(newOwner);

      //update vehicle
      v.setRegistration(newRegistration);
   }
```

}

Similarly for the `Drivable` related methods.  Driving to a Destination may have maps and path finding algorithms, updating fuel available... most of which should not be in `Vehicle`.  Instead some kind of `NavigationService` can be used to handle most of that and only tell the vehicle how fast to drive, when to make turns and how far to drive in particular directions:

```
 public class NavigationService{
    private Map map; // a real map with distances between drivable locations

    ...

    public void navigateTo(Vehicle v, Destination to){
       Location from = v.getLocation();

       ...//complex business logic to find best path from current to destination.
       Directions directions = computeDirections(from, to);

       //for each step in the directions call low level methods
       //on vehicle to tell it how to get to destination
       for(Step step : directions){
           v.turn(step.getCardinalDirection()); // i.e. north south east west 
           v.travelFor(step.getDistance()); //perhaps vehicle tracks fuel consumption
       }

    }

    private Directions computeDirections(Location from, Destination to){
         ..//use map to find best path
    }
 }
```

Vehicle can still keep track of fuel

```
 public class Vehicle{
   ...
   private double fuelLeft;

   public void travelFor(Distance distance){
       double spent = distance.asMiles() * this.getMpg();
       fuelLeft -= spent;
       if(fuelLeft < 0){
         throw new OutOfFuelException();
       }
       //update current location by moving the distance in the given direction
       //(which was set by turn()
       this.currentLocation = currentLocation.move(direction, distance);
   }
```

}

Now Vehicle only contains information about the actual car.  Methods not related to the actual Vehicle such as  for how to get from one place to another has been factored out to new classes.  These classes are free to change in the future without affecting `Vechile`'s API at all.

Comment: That's very interesting and very well thought out. Thanks for taking the time to post. I'm going to have to absorb it and come back with questions. My immediate reaction is that you are implying that the Vehicle be restricted just to capturing data and all things it can do be in other classes. That surprises me: my understanding of OO philosophy is that the data and methods for using the data should be combined. But I'll need to consider it further. thanks.

Comment: Ok I've tried refactoring using the mechanism you've proposed here and have found a number of issues. I'd be happy to post them if you're interested in the discussion but you've given me a lot of food for thought already so will only follow up if you want to discuss further.

Comment: @sprinter I didn't mean "all things it can do [should] be in other classes".  But Vehicle should only do 1 thing.  Be a Vehicle, anything else such as navigation should be done in another class which then tells the Vehicle how.  I recommend you read up on Domain Driven Design to see how to better model your Domain Objects

Comment: I have read Domain Driven Design and apply the principles regularly. This is code I inherited and want to refactor without rewritting from scratch. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

How about using composite rather than inherit.

```
interface Drivable {
    void driveTo(Destination destination);
}

interface Sellable {
    void sellTo(Person purchaser);
}

class DriveFunction implement Drivable{
}

class SellInformation implement Sellable{
}

class Vehicle {
    private final Drivable drivableVehicle;
    private final Sellable sellableVehicle;

    public Vehicle(Drivable drivable,Sellable sellable){
    }

    public void driveTo(Destination destination) {
        drivableVehicle.driveTo(destination);
    }

    public void sellTo(Person purchaser) {
        sellableVehicle.sellTo(purchaser);
    }
}
```

If add a new function to Drivable, all you need it add a function to DriveFunction class. Only if you need to expose the method from Vehicle, you should add a delegate method into the Vehicle.

**Update**

Maybe the reverse delegation is the right answer

Keep Vehicle as original.

```
class DriveFunction implement Drivable{
     DriveFunction(Vehicle vehicle){
     }

     void driveTo(Destination destination){
         vehicle.driveTo(destination);
     }
}
```

Then, if Drivacle interface changed, we don't need to touch Vehicle if unnecessary.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm assuming you're thinking of the situation in which Drivable and Sellable are used for other purposes as well? In other words, they might have methods I don't wish to expose in Vehicle. That's not really the case I'm talking about here: the interfaces have been created solely for the purpose of splitting the Vehicle class.

Comment: @sprinter, Changed the solution. I am still not sure if I catch the point.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining it well enough. Or perhaps there isn't a good answer! Thanks for your suggestions - I'll give it some further thought.